# Encontrar e idênticas em uma coluna os valores falsos e verdadeiros

Tags: sql

Tenho uma consulta SQL que me traz o resultado em número na coluna A. Porém devido alguns números ter passado passado por outros processos, a consulta retorna em alguns momentos com o número duplicado. Queria saber se exista alguma forma de trazer em uma coluna específica os números duplicados, classificando como verdadeiro e falso.

Comment: sim tem, basta agrupar e contar (usar *count* e *group by*) e usar *having* para trazer os dados que aparecem mais de uma vez. Faça uma pergunta por [sql + duplicados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+duplicados) e vai encontrar perguntas semelhantes